# Flutter failing behind proxy: Proxy failed to establish tunnel (407 Proxy Authentication Required)

Tags: macos, dart, flutter

I'm just getting started setting up Flutter to run on my Mac. I'm running from behind a corporate proxy and every time I try to run a 
`flutter create app` I am seeing `pub get failed`.

I have set my proxy settings correctly in my bash profile:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://[myUsername]:[myPassword]@[myProxy]:[myPort]"
export HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY
export ALL_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY
export http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY
export https_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY
export all_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY
export GRPC_PROXY_EXP=$HTTP_PROXY
export grpc_proxy_exp=$HTTP_PROXY
export NO_PROXY=localhost,126.0.0.0,127.0.0.1
export STRICT_SSL=false
export strict_ssl=$STRICT_SSL
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
export node_tls_reject_unauthorized=$NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED
```

Running `flutter doctor` I am seeing my proxy as being set up correctly:

```
✓] Proxy Configuration
    • HTTP_PROXY is set
    • NO_PROXY is localhost,126.0.0.0,127.0.0.1
    • NO_PROXY contains 127.0.0.1
    • NO_PROXY contains localhost
```

Looking at the Github issues I see others are having [the exact same problems](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2111) but don't see any solutions.

My current error:

```
Proxy failed to establish tunnel (407 Proxy Authentication Required)    
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 349:7                                BoundHostedSource._throwFriendlyError
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 150:7                                BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
package:pub/src/source.dart 167:12                                      BoundSource.getVersions
package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 76:44                        PackageLister._versions.<fn>.<fn>
dart:async                                                              runZoned
package:pub/src/http.dart 272:10                                        withDependencyType
package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 75:33                        PackageLister._versions.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
dart:async                                                              new Future.sync
package:async/src/async_memoizer.dart 43:42                             AsyncMemoizer.runOnce
package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 74:58                        PackageLister._versions
package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 111:21                       PackageLister.countVersions
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 354:44                       VersionSolver._choosePackageVersion.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
package:pub/src/utils.dart 301:39                                       minByAsync
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 350:25                       VersionSolver._choosePackageVersion
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 97:22                        VersionSolver.solve
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
package:pub/src/solver.dart 35:10                                       resolveVersions.<fn>
package:pub/src/log.dart 378:18                                         progress
package:pub/src/solver.dart 32:10                                       resolveVersions
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 203:24                                  Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
package:pub/src/command/get.dart 41:23                                  GetCommand.run
package:args/command_runner.dart 194:27                                 CommandRunner.runCommand
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 171:39                              PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
dart:async                                                              new Future.sync
package:pub/src/utils.dart 109:12                                       captureErrors.<fn>
dart:async                                                              runZoned
package:pub/src/utils.dart 126:5                                        captureErrors
package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 171:13                              PubCommandRunner.runCommand
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 119:11                              PubCommandRunner.run
===== asynchronous gap ===========================                      
/b/s/w/ir/k/src/third_party/dart/third_party/pkg/pub/bin/pub.dart 8:22  main
This is an unexpected error. Please run                                 

    pub --trace '--verbosity=warning' get --no-precompile               

and include the logs in an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/new
Running "flutter packages get" in my_app...                             
pub get failed (1)
```

I'm just getting started with Flutter and I'm not sure if this is related to Flutter, or Dart.

Comment: anyone have any answer to this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

add https://pub.dartlang.org to your proxy rules,I fix it with this