# Setup Flutter behind proxy (407 Proxy Authentication Required)

Tags: windows, flutter, http, proxy

I can't setup Flutter from behind corporate proxy. When I run `flutter doctor` I get `407 Proxy Authentication Required`. I have correctly setuped `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy`. I get no problems with any other CLI apps.

```sh
$ flutter doctor
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Proxy failed to establish tunnel (407 Proxy Authentication Required)
Error (69): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
```

Am using Windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138235/flutter-failing-behind-proxy-proxy-failed-to-establish-tunnel-407-proxy-authen

Comment: Tried that, now I get TLS error.
`Got TLS error trying to find package test at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...`